# PHP Mail Script working but email not arriving

Tags: php

I've written the following PHP script to send an email based on a forms input:

```
<?php

$to=$_POST["email"];

$subject=$_POST["subject"];

$message=$_POST["message"]."<br />".'<img src=imgdir/'.$_POST["banimg"].'"/><br /><br />'.'<img src=addir/'.$_POST["adimg"].'"/><br /><br />';

$from="foo@example.com";

$headers=array();
$headers[]="MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[]="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[]="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$headers[]="From: ".$from;

$advertised=mail($to,$subject,$message,join("\n",$headers));

if ($advertised){
echo "Working";
}

?>
```

My echo "Working" returns as true, so the script is completing, however, the email is not being delivered.

Is there an issue within my code here?

Dustin

Comment: Did you check your spam folders?

Comment: From the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php): *It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php manual states that `Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).`

It is possible that is a source of the problem.  Aside from that, make sure that your email settings in php.ini are configured properly for the local server, and that a mta such as sendmail or smtp is installed and running on the server.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the header issue out.  At this stage, I'm assuming that it's a server issue.

Comment: May be there is an issue with the server mail settings